# iterate multiple handlebars objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

Friends help me I'm trying to iterate these objects with handlebars

```
RowDataPacket {
idUser: 1,
username: 'xxxxxx',
password: 'xxxxx',
fullname: 'Julian Rincon'},

RowDataPacket {
idUser: 2,
username: 'xxxxx',
password: 'xxxxx',
fullname: 'Sharyn arias' }
```

these objects are stored in array users[], 
iterating the array with {{#each}} I only get the first data of the array

```
<option value="{{linksUpdate.idUser}}">{{linksUpdate.fullname}}</option>
 <option value="">Seleccione una Opcion</option>
       {{#users}}                            
        <option value="{{idUser}}">{{fullname}}</option>                           
        {{/users}}
```

I only get the first data  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhZYm.png) help me please

Comment: Your data does not look like an array

Answer (score 0):

Look at my snippet below and try to apply it on your `data`.
http://jsfiddle.net/umospfnk/1/

```js
$(function() {
var source = $("#document-template").html();
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
var html = template(data);
$('#DocumentResults').html(html);
});

var data = [{
  users: [{
    idUser: 1,
    username: 'xxxxxx',
    password: 'xxxxx',
    fullname: 'Julian Rincon'
  }, {
    idUser: 2,
    username: 'xxxxx',
    password: 'xxxxx',
    fullname: 'Sharyn arias'
  }]
}];
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/1.0.0/handlebars.js"></script>


<div id="DocumentResults"></div>
<script id="document-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <div>
        {{#each this}}
          <option value="">Seleccione una Opcion</option>
            
          {{#users}}                            
            <option value="{{idUser}}">{{fullname}}</option>    
          {{/users}}
        {{/each}}
    </div>
</script>
```